# Azure Table Storage: Which string comparison method is used?

Tags: c#, azure, string-comparison, azure-table-storage

I want to query Azure Table Storage for ranges of entities using `RowKey >= MyRangeStart AND RowKey <= MyRangeEnd`.

However, I am unable to find documentation stating exactly which string comparison method is used by Azure Table Storage. For example, in C#, `"a".CompareTo("A")` produces different results depending on the current culture.

From experimentation, it seems that the comparison performed by Azure Table Storage is the same as string.CompareOrdinal. However, it would be nice to have confidence that this is definitely the comparison being used.

Is there any official documentation that describes the string comparison used?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/Designing-a-Scalable-Partitioning-Strategy-for-Azure-Table-Storage?redirectedfrom=MSDN), **lexical comparison** is used for clustered index. Hence it is the most probable scenario for your case.

> The sort order is observed in all query responses. **Lexical comparisons are used during the sorting operation**. Therefore, a string value of "111" will appear before a string value of "2". In some cases, you may want the order to be numeric. To sort in a numeric and ascending order, you will need to use fixed-length, zero-padded strings. In the previous example, using "002" will allow it to appear before "111".

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I did notice that it speaks of "lexical comparisons." However, my understanding is that this only means that it is a string comparison and not, for example, an integer comparison. I understand this. However, there are different ways to compare strings. I'm interested in knowing for sure that an ordinal string compare is used (using the unicode value for each character).